# Restrict access to the Trash folder in Posts

Tags: posts, content-restriction, trash

I want to restrict users from deleting posts permanently. How do I restrict access to the Trash folder in Posts? This is the only page were the users can delete their posts **permanently**.

The only solutions that I have so far is:

1) Adding this to stylesheet:

```
li.trash {
    display: none;
}
```

But both me and you know that this is a dummy fix and more importantly, it just hides the link that goes to the Trash folder for **all** users.

2) Remove the capability `delete_posts` for none-editors. The problem with this is that the users will not be able to move their posts to the trash folder (which is a feature that is essential for my platform).

Do you know of a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the filter we prevent the `Trash` link from being printed.
And with the action, redirect back to the post listing page if the user tries to access the URL directly (`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_status=trash&post_type=post`).

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-post', 'wpse_74488_remove_trash_link' );
add_action( 'admin_head-edit.php', 'wpse_74488_block_trash_access' );

function wpse_74488_remove_trash_link( $views ) 
{
    if( !current_user_can( 'delete_plugins' ) )
        unset( $views['trash'] );

    return $views;
}

function wpse_74488_block_trash_access()
{
    global $current_screen;

    if( 
        'post' != $current_screen->post_type 
        || 'trash' != $_GET['post_status'] 
    )
        return;

    if( !current_user_can( 'delete_plugins' ) )
    {
        wp_redirect( admin_url() . 'edit.php' ); 
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works elegantly! I'm impressed, great solution, upvoted and accepted!