# Delete post from admin but not from database

Tags: posts, customization

Is it possible to have a post not deleted from the MySQL database on deleting from the wp-admin panel ?

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/74488/12615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default wordpress do not delete posts but rather moves them to the trash. They do not appear in the normal posts admin, but you can still see them in the trash and recover them from it.

Comment: But what if someone deletes it from the trash in wp-admin ? Is there a way to get this from MySQL database ?

Comment: Not unless you have a backup for the DB, and even then It might not be trivial to restore the post if new posts where published since then.